# How to manage inventory using macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get Excel to work as a inventory scan reader. 
When i scan any item using barcode scanner,it should recognize the item in the excel and add my current inventory.

In my excel i have following data  COL A is DESCRIPTION,COL B is Barcode,COL C is QTY_before sale and COL D is Current_scan_stock.

Column D will be empty and as i scan the barcode it should recognize the item and add the qty, every-time i scan same barcode it should add +1

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. On the other hand, there are many questions like yours that you can look up.

Comment: How you will connect the results from the scanner with the excel?

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to pass in excel the bar code you could use the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rngToSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim LookingValue As String

    'Create a with statement refer to the sheet that your data are store
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Assigg to LookingValue the barcode scanned
        LookingValue = "1234"
        'Find the last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Set the range to search for the barcode in
        Set rngToSearch = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        'Set to rngFound the results from the find
        Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find(LookingValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
        'If the result is nothing
        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
            'Message box
            MsgBox "Barcode was not found."
        'if you find a result
        Else
            'Add 1 to the existing value
            .Cells(rngFound.Row, 4).Value = 1 + .Cells(rngFound.Row, 4).Value
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```